# How can I convert Json data into real data android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have an android code, which gets data from the database mysql and am using php to achieve that . The code works nicely but now the challenge is pare the json data .

This is the json i receive.

```
{"university":[{"University_Name":"New York  University "},{"University_Name":"University Of Mississippi"},{"University_Name":"University Of London"},{"University_Name":"Birmingham University"}]}
```

I want the app to display like Birmingham University and so on .

below is my android code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    // 
    TextView resultView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        StrictMode.enableDefaults(); // This line is very usefull 
        resultView  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); // Timeout
                                                                                // Limit
        HttpResponse response;
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://10.0.0.54:80/connector/get_categories.php");
            json.put("service", "GOOGLE");
            Log.i("jason Object", json.toString());
            post.setHeader("json", json.toString());
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
            se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));

            post.setEntity(se);
            response = client.execute(post);
            /* Checking response */
            if (response != null) {
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); // Get the
                                                                    // data in
                                                                        // the
                                                                  // entity
                String a = convertStreamToString(in);
                Log.i("Read from Server", a);


                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "We are Connected";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, a, duration);
                toast.show();




                //This code displays


                resultView.setText(a);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();



        }


    }
        private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }





    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView resultView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StrictMode.enableDefaults(); // This line is very usefull 
        resultView  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

        getUniversity(new WebServicesCallListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                resultView.setText(response);
                try{
                    JSONObject jsonRespone  = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray universityJsonArray =  jsonRespone.getJSONArray("university");

                    ArrayList<String> universityList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i=0;i<universityJsonArray.length();i++){
                        universityList.add(universityJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("University_Name"));
                    }

                    for(String university : universityList){
                        System.out.print("University Name : "+ university);
                    }
                }catch (Throwable e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void getUniversity(final WebServicesCallListener targer){

        new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>(){

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); // Timeout
                // Limit
                HttpResponse response;
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://10.0.0.54:80/connector/get_categories.php");
                    json.put("service", "GOOGLE");
                    Log.i("jason Object", json.toString());
                    post.setHeader("json", json.toString());
                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
                    se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

                    post.setEntity(se);
                    response = client.execute(post);

                    /* Checking response */
                    if (response != null) {
                        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); // Get the

                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                        String line = null;
                        try {
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            try {
                                in.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        return sb.toString();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return "";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                targer.onResponse(s);
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    public interface WebServicesCallListener {
        public void onResponse(String response);
    }

}
```

Comment: The first code u gave me it did display universities very well but it was not from the db but now this new one does not . and this collect from db

Comment: Am getting there now a bit by a bit I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

use this code to parse the data

```
JSONObject jObj=new JSONObject(a);

    JSONArray dataArray=jObj.optJSONArray("university");
    List<String>  dataList=new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0;i<dataArray.length();i++)
    {
        dataList.add(dataArray.optJSONObject(i).getString("University_Name"));
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,""+dataArray.optJSONObject(i).getString("University_Name"), duration);
            toast.show();
    }
```

just replace your toast with my code

Comment: here a is the string you converted

Comment: Can U please integrate it in my codes and display in Toast?

Answer (score 0):

Use gson to convert JSON to objects.

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using Google GSON library.
try it [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) , GOSN library is converts json data to normal java classes and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is all a bit hackish, as others have written you should use something like GSON. Anyway, if you want a toast notification for each item:

```
try {
    JSONArray array = new JSONObject(a).getJSONArray("university");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        String name = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("University_Name");
        Toast.makeText(context, name, duration).show();
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

if you want one toast displaying all items separated by a comma, for example:

```
String name = "";
String separator = ", ";

try {
    JSONArray array = new JSONObject(a).getJSONArray("university");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        if (i == array.length() - 1) {
            separator = "";
        }
        name = name
            + array.getJSONObject(i).getString("University_Name")
            + separator;
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Toast.makeText(context, name, duration).show();
```

---

### ** UPDATED for inserting result into listview **

A very simple example to get you started:

First create an xml layout like this (let's call it **list_item.xml**:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Create your adapter class (let's call this **UniversitiesAdapter.java**):

```
public class UniversitiesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private JSONArray array;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public UniversitiesAdapter(Context context, JSONArray array) {
    this.array = array;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView textView;
}

public int getCount() {
    return array.length();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, true);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.textView.setText(array.getJSONObject(position).getString("University_Name"));

    return view;

}
```

}

In your activity:

```
private UniversitiesAdapter adapter;
private ListView listView;

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);
```

once you get your response (the value of 'a'):

```
adapter = new UniversitiesAdapter (context, new JSONObject(a).getJSONArray("university"));
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: This is good man but  now am strugling to  display it in a List View

Comment: Well that requires a bit more work than your OP asked. I edited my response above.